# Elasticsearch bulk upsert throwing status 400, not clear why

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to update one field of a bunch of documents via a bulk upsert in a python application. I am successfully able to use upsert one at a time, but the bulk helper fails. I really need to do this in bulk because there is so much data, it uses way too many requests to do this one at a time.

The data looks like:

```
{"foo"{"..."}, "bar": {...}}
```

The function for single upsert is:

```
async def upsert(self, _id, datanum, _type):
    datanum = eval(datanum)
    self.logger.info('Updating')
    
    await self._es.update(index=self._index, id=hashlib.md5(_id.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(),
                              doc={f'{_type}': datanum, 'doc_as_upsert': True})
```

So, based off the examples I see documented [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/main/examples/bulk-ingest/bulk-ingest.py) and [here](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/helpers.html#bulk-helpers), I  came up with this function:

```
def upload(data, _type):
    parsed_iter = enumerate(create_merged_data(data=data, _type="foo"))
    conn = await self.connect()
    docs = []
    print(f'[~] Uploading to elastic ...')
    for i, _ in parsed_iter:
        _id = (json.loads(_)['ip'])
        _id = hashlib.md5(_id.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        docs.append({"_op_type": 'update',
            "_index": f"{self.index}",
            "_id": _id,
            "doc": {f"{_type}": f"{_}"},
            "doc_as_upsert": True})
    await helpers.async_bulk(client=self._es, actions=data, index=self._index)
    await self.es.join()
```

But for some reason, the bulk fails while individually the upsert works fine. The traceback I am getting:

```
File "/home/anon/PycharmProjects/xxxxxxx/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/elasticsearch/helpers/actions.py", line 274, in _process_bulk_chunk_success
raise BulkIndexError(f"{len(errors)} document(s) failed to index.", errors)
elasticsearch.helpers.BulkIndexError: 168 document(s) failed to index.
```

It is not clear to me what I am doing wrong here... It would seem to me that I am following the examples in the elasticsearch docs almost exactly. Can anyone offer any insight?

EDIT:

Upon further inspection, the specific error that is causing this to fail is:

'object mapping for [foo] tried to parse field [foo] as object, but found a concrete value'

EDIT Again: Apparently, the data was NOT being updated correctly, but rather a new "foo": {...} was being *appended* to the document ... I don't understand what is going on here. I tried so many different things. Deleting the index, recreating it, manually setting the mapping, etc. Pretty much banging my head against the desk at this point. Please help...

What would be super helpful, because I have not been able to find a helpful example anywhere... is a short, concise tutorial that explains how to do the following things with the python elastic lib **bulk** helpers:

1. Create an index (and set the mappings, if need be)
2. Index some data like:

   {"foo"{"key": "value"}}
3. upsert that document so it is now:

   {"foo"{"key": "value"}, "bar": {"key2": "value2"}}

I would so appreciate it. Have spent far too much of my life debugging elasticsearch.

EDIT: the create_merged_data function:

```
def create_merged_data(data, _type):
        data = generate_data(data, _type)
        for x, _ in enumerate(parsed):
            if _type == 'foo':
                host = _['address']
                data_structure = {'ip': host,
                                  'last_updated': time.time(),
                                  'foo': _,
                                  'bar': {}}
            else:
                host = _['address']
                data_structure = {'ip': host,
                                  'last_updated': time.time(),
                                  'foo': {},
                                  'bar': _}
            yield json.dumps(data_structure)
```

Comment: Anything useful in your ES server logs? Also the BulkIndexError that is raised includes a list of errors that you can check individually.

Comment: Yes, you are right - I updated the question  to reflect the more specific error.

Comment: There you go, it means in the first document you indexed `foo` was an object and then another document contained `foo` with a concrete value (string, number, etc), and that doesn't work.

Comment: I don't quite understand what happened here, but I recreated the index and then it just kind of worked.

Comment: Cool, glad it eventually worked out

Comment: Actually I just inspected my data closely and realized that it is not doing what I want it to do. Instead of updating the field in question, it seems to be appending another {'fooi: {}} to the document.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be related to ES at all, more likely to the logic you're using to build up the data, can you share what `create_merged_data` does?

Comment: Yes, I will update the question